# Node container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a container with node and npm to execute npm i in docjer compose.

I have the next service defined in docker-compose

```
 node-builder:
    build:
      context: ./node
    container_name: aloware-node-builder
    restart: no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /Users/juanblariza/Projects/aloware/api-core
        target: /var/www/api-core
    working_dir: /var/www/api-core
    command: [ "npm", "i", "--omit=optional"]
```

then I have this dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    git \
    make \
    g++

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main \
    python2

RUN npm i -g npm@9
```

and when I run docker-compose up node-builder I got the following error:

```
docker-compose up node-builder
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container aloware-node-builder  Created                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
Attaching to aloware-node-builder
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN config optional Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN config `--include=optional` to include them.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN config 
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN config     Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated consolidate@0.15.1: Please upgrade to consolidate v1.0.0+ as it has been modernized with several long-awaited fixes implemented. Maintenance is supported by Forward Email at https://forwardemail.net ; follow/watch https://github.com/ladjs/consolidate for updates and release changelog
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated flag-icon-css@2.9.0: The project has been renamed to flag-icons
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated vue@2.7.16: Vue 2 has reached EOL and is no longer actively maintained. See https://v2.vuejs.org/eol/ for more details.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
aloware-node-builder  | npm WARN deprecated v-calendar@1.1.1: Breaking changes introduced in 2.0
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | added 978 packages, changed 11 packages, and audited 1502 packages in 5m
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | 106 packages are looking for funding
aloware-node-builder  |   run `npm fund` for details
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | 41 vulnerabilities (21 moderate, 20 high)
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | To address issues that do not require attention, run:
aloware-node-builder  |   npm audit fix
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
aloware-node-builder  |   npm audit fix --force
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | Some issues need review, and may require choosing
aloware-node-builder  | a different dependency.
aloware-node-builder  | 
aloware-node-builder  | Run `npm audit` for details.
aloware-node-builder exited with code 0
```

The source path is a project with a package.json, but I can't find the error

Comment: There's no long-running process in the container.  The only thing you have it run is `npm i`, and that immediately exits (successfully, with code 0).  I'd normally expect `RUN npm ci` to be a step in your Dockerfile, so that `node_modules` is contained in the image, and doesn't need to be rebuilt every time you run the container.  Make sure you delete the `volumes:` from the Compose file so this work isn't hidden when you create the container.

Comment: okok, I thought that exit code 0 was an error. Because this docker compose has other 2 containers that use node-builder

Comment: In Unix, exit code 0 is generally "success", and anything non-zero is an error.